# RegisterStartupScript only working part of the time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a method that pulls html from a webservice and displays this info in a series of popup windows. To achieve this I wrote a javascript to create the popup:

```
function dynamicPopup(title, HTMLstring) {
    newWindow = window.open();
    newDocument = newWindow.document;
    newDocument.write(HTMLstring);
    newDocument.title = title;
};
```

The I loop through the results calling the following for every object returned from the webservice.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), DateTime.Now.ToString(), resultMessage, true);
```

The problem is that it works when only a few popups are returned but if 15 are returned then only about 8-10 of them are displayed.

As a bandage I added a Wait after RegisterStartupScript and that seems to work well but results in slower delivery times. Does anyone know any other way to address this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling multiple `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` in a loop, first construct script that needs to be run (e.g. using StringBuilder, combine multiple `resultMessage` separated by ';') and then call `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` only once to execute resulting string.

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't think of such a simple fix.

Comment: np ;) sometimes all you need is just fresh pair of eyes

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use Guid in order to identify your script with key

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

so

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), resultMessage, true);
```